# Visual Web Developer 2010 localhost formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

If I debug my site on Visual Web Developer Express 2010 (i.e.:http://localhost:67888) the formatting is all wrong, as if its ignoring the CSS.
Its fine on the web server.
How to fix this little problem?

Comment: Really need more info. Can you post the script that includes the css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to tell from the lack of info. Its most likely that you are referencing the CSS via the full URL (e.g. http://mysite.com/styles/mystyles.css).

Try using a relative path.

Comment: asp.net builds the file itself and calls it like this: <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 0):

Open it up in Chrome then use inspect element (right click on page) click on the resources tab and see if their is an error against the stylesheet